# Definition of adjectives

Tags: word-meaning, definition

For example, ‘destruction’ means the act of destructing and the act is destructing.

Here is my question:
‘happiness’ means the quality of being happy.

Is the quality being happy? I mean, is being happy quality?

Comment: Your question is not about grammar and idiom, it's about meanings and definitions (semantics). This is not the right site to address it.

Comment: @Ronald Sole Please give me some help I love you....

Comment: Most people would regard happiness as a quality.

Comment: @Ronald Sole you mean being happy is quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Happiness" is a noun.  It is a quality or characteristic (특질) that something can have or not have.

> I found happiness when my daughter was born.

"Being happy" is a gerund phrase that could be used to say what the abstract noun "happiness" is.  Just like "being fast" could be used to say what "speed" is.

> Happiness is the quality of being happy.

> Speed is the quality of going fast.

Quality, in this sense does not mean "level of excellence"

Comment: Good writing in Korean I love you there’s nobody but you

Comment: Wiktionary has glosses for each sense of a word.  It is useful to use a bilingual dictionary to understand the meaning of difficult words.

Comment: okay ♥ actually Korean is harder because there are many 한자어